Yaml-cpp emits an doublequoted yaml string when emitted in an destructor
I‘m trying to serialize some data using yaml-cpp on destruction of an object. This normally works fine but as soon as that object is static something weird happens: Every string, also keys of maps, is wrapped in double quotes.
Example
struct EmitterTest
{
    ~EmitterTest()
    {
        Serialize();
    }

    void Serialize()
    {
        YAML::Emitter out;

        out << YAML::BeginMap << YAML::Key << "Test";
        out << YAML::BeginMap;
        out << YAML::Key << "String1" << YAML::Value << "String1";
        out << YAML::Key << "String2" << YAML::Value << "String2";
        out << YAML::Key << "String3" << YAML::Value << "Foo";
        out << YAML::EndMap;
        out << YAML::EndMap;

        std::cout << out.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}

static EmitterTest s_Test;

int main()
{
    s_Test.Serialize();
}

Expected output:
Test:
  String1: String1
  String2: String2
  String3: Foo
Test:
  String1: String1
  String2: String2
  String3: Foo

Actual output:
Test:
  String1: String1
  String2: String2
  String3: Foo
"Test":
  "String1": "String1"
  "String2": "String2"
  "String3": "Foo"

Note that this behavior only occurs when the Serialize() function is called once before destruction.

but as soon as that object is static something weird happens: -- And in that, you've lost all control of when the destructor actually gets called after main.   Maybe at that point, important aspects of yaml-cpp are in a state where you cannot rely on it working properly.

Judging by this question and the comments there, I suspect it could be something to do with global locale being destructed or something.

The solution to this is not emitting in an destructor, where you don't know when its beeing destructed like a static variable.
